# I'm getting more than one result per left row from a LEFT JOIN with a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

With this query I'm supposed to get the latest message from the chats table for every agreement I get, as well as all the information including business name, etc.

I kind of solved it using GROUP BY in the subquery, but it is not the way I wanna fix this, because I don't understand why it does act as a RIGHT JOIN, and WHY doesn't it order it in the way I meant in the subquery:

```
SELECT agreements.id, agreements.`date`, agreements.state, business.name, chat.message
FROM ((agreements JOIN
       business_admin
       ON agreements.business = business_admin.business AND business_admin.user = 1
      ) LEFT JOIN
     business
     ON business.id = agreements.business
    ) LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT agreements_chat.agreement, agreements_chat.message
     FROM agreements_chat
     WHERE origin = 0 
     ORDER BY agreements_chat.`date` DESC
    ) AS chat
    ON agreements.id = chat.agreement
```

I really appreciate your help, thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you using parentheses around your joins?  Why are you using `order by` in a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because the subquery in your left join returns more than one rows, hence the duplication of rows you get.

```
SELECT  agreements.id,
        agreements.`date`,
        agreements.state,
        business.name,
        chat.message
FROM    agreements
JOIN    business_admin
ON      agreements.business = business_admin.business AND
        business_admin.user = 1
LEFT JOIN
        business
ON      business.id = agreements.business
LEFT JOIN
        agreements_chat chat
ON      chat.origin = 0 AND
        chat.agreement = agreements.id
LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  agreement, max(`date`) last_date
            FROM    agreements_chat
            GROUP BY agreement
        ) last_chat
ON      chat.agreement = last_chat.agreement AND
        chat.`date` = last_chat.last_date
```

Note that (as per @GordonLinoff comment) you don't need parenthese around your joins.

Comment: This wouldn't return 1 subquery record per agreement, just one subquery record total.

Comment: Correct, I edited it. Now it should work as expected

Comment: You where right with the parentheses, it was kind of useless, just had sense in my mind for structuring.
The LIMIT 1 solves it perfecly as I wanted, but the think I don't understand is why the LEFT JOIN acts like a JOIN, and I tried removing the last entire LEFT JOIN and it only gave me a row, so the left part is just one row
Thank you all anyway :D